# file.truncate() does not work even the path exists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, truncate, oserror

I am trying to make a file manipulation. The thing I want to make is to delete a piece of byte from file and shift the rest of the file by that much amount of byte to the deleted piece's place. I have this code:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r+b")
mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
s=""
for i in range(10 - len(arg_list[0])) :
    s+="\0"
s+=arg_list[0]
index = 0

while mm[:10]:
    current_type_name = mm[:10].decode()
    if current_type_name == s:
        f.seek(110*index)
        f.truncate()
        f.write(mm[110*(index+1):])
    else:    
        mm = mm[110:]
        index += 1
```

Everything works properly except that f.truncate() function. I have already tried f.truncate(n) where n is an integer but I am getting still error below.

Error:

```
File "main.py", line 109, in delete_type
    f.truncate()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I have searched what causes this, some says it related with filepath or file does not exist. But I am %100 percent sure that I am running the file through the console in same path and file already exists. Also I have tried absolute path both with \ and r"" ways. But still I got same error.

One more thing, when I tried to comment f.truncate() and rearrange the while loop not to fall infinite loop, the code is working. And also I use code structures in another functions, surprisingly it doesn't casue error.